A man cashes a check for $d$ dollars and $c$ cents
I know this question has been asked before, but the answer to the previously posted question does not address my question about the problem. I will restate the problem:
A man cashes a check for $d$ dollars and $c$ cents, but the teller gives him $c$ dollars and $d$ cents instead. The man doesn't notice the mistake until he has spent 23 cents, at which point he has $2d$ dollars and $2c$ cents. What was the original amount of the check?
As in the previously posed question, I come up with the linear equation:
$98c-199d=23$
However, the posted answer to this question uses congruences, which haven't been introduced yet in the elementary number theory book I am using. So, I have been trying to solve it with what amounts to a brute-force method. I know that $c<100$, but since the teller gives the man $d$ cents, it must be that $d<100$ also. I solved the linear equation for c:
$c=23/98+(199/98)*d$
This means I must find a multiple of 199 less 23 that is evenly divisible by 98, while also satisfying the other conditions. Without knowing congruences, this was a trial-and-error process. I found that $d=25$ and $c=51$ satisfies the equation and answers the problem, but I was dissatisfied with this process. Do I just need to read on in my book? Or is there another approach?

I suggest:  link to the duplicate question.  Also...here, instead of "congruence" you could just use "remainder".  I doubt any subtle properties of congruence are involved here...sure, the Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees a solution (if certain tests are passed) but you still have to find it and that often comes down to a search.

$$\begin{align} 98\mid!!! \overbrace{199}^{\color{#c00}3+2(98)}!!!d+23!\iff! 98\mid \color{#c00}3d&+!!!\overbrace{23}^{98\color{#0af}{-75}}!!!!\iff! 98\mid \overbrace{3d!\color{#0af}{-75}}^{3(d-25)}!\iff! 98\mid d-\color{darkorange}{25}\
{\rm i.e.}\ \ \ \bmod 98!:\ {-}\color{#c00}3d &\equiv 23!\iff! d \equiv \dfrac{-23}3 \equiv \dfrac{\color{#0af}{75^{\phantom{|}}}}3 \equiv \color{darkorange}{25}\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

We made the quotient $-23/3,$ exact by computing a $\rm\color{#0af}{multiple}$ of $,3,$ that is $\equiv -23\pmod{!98},,$
i.e. $,3\mid -23!+!98k = 1!-!k + 3(-8!+!33k)\iff 3\mid \color{#0a0}{1!-!k},$ so $,3\mid -23!+!98(\color{#0a0}1)= \color{#0af}{75},,$  see twiddling / inverse reciprocity, and other methods there - including the general extended Euclidean algorithm. Such calculations become much clearer once you learn congruences (modular arithmetic).

The above method is essentially an optimization of the extended Euclidean algorithm for the case when it terminates in two steps.

How would you solve the problem by purely intuitive methods?  With $~(c,d) = (2,1),~$ you end up with $~98c - 199d = -3.~$  So, if $~(c,d) = (N \times 2, N \times 1),~$ you end up with $~98c - 199d = -3N.~$  Then, when you add one further $~98~$ term, you end up with $~98 - 3N,~$ which you want to equal $~23.~$  This implies that $~3N = 75,~$ which implies that $~N = 25.~$  So, you end up with $$(c,d) = (51,25) \implies 98c - 199d = 23.$$

When doing the substitutions above in Bill's equations, I see that $3+2(98)=199$, and $98-75=23$, but what allows us to "drop" the $2(98)$ and the 98 in the $98-75$? Is it because we are not in an equation anymore, but rather looking at 98 dividing into an expression? So any term that is clearly a multiple of 98 can be removed from consideration? I can see how the congruence relation is much more straightforward.

It's because $,d\mid a!+!nd!\iff! d\mid a;,$ equivalently if $,a\equiv \bar a\pmod{!d},$ then $,d\mid a\iff d\mid \bar a,,$ see divisibility mod reduction. $\ \ $

Please don't significantly change your questions. If you have a different question you should ask it in a new question.
